# Qlikview Wildcard in a variable

Tags: wildcard, qlikview

I have this string:

```
Sum (if(left(SeasonCalc,3) = '171', Fsgantal*ShoesMen))
```

`SeasonCalc` is a sales period for the year, i.e. the Season.
`Fsgantal` is the Number of shoes sold
`ShoesMen` is to only show the number of shoes sold that are Men's shoes.

The season is named like 17S1... 17S2... 18S1 etc.

What I want to do is to change the Season as the sales period changes and do that by using a **Wildcard in the variable**. **Is this possible?**

I know it's *possible to use a variable* to set the sales period, we do this already, but then I'd have to define `*ShoesMen` or `*ShoesLadies` etc. for every string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but following your example, I would guess that something like this could work :

```
Sum(if(WildMatch(SeasonCalc, '*S1'), Fsgantal*ShoesMen))
```

WildMatch will return true if it matches one of the a wildcard expression given as a parameter.

Comment: This works. I changed it to `Sum(if(WildMatch(SeasonCalc, '171*'), Fsgantal*ShoesMen))` (sorry I misplaced the S and the 1). I get a correct value and will now go ahead and create a variable out of the `171*` in my script. That should do it and give me more control.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards can also be used in Set Analysis, also better performance :

```
Sum({<SeasonCalc={'*S1'}>}, Fsgantal*ShoesMen))
```